# How to pass props from child to map() in parent's component?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have child component  which represents simple . My idea is to pass some fetched data to its parent component. I have state like this:`state: { countries: [] }`, and I fetched data to it in `componentDidMount()`. `state.countries` is filled with some id and countryName values. When I write code like this

```
   <select
      name="country"
      defaultValue="country"
      onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
    >
      <option disabled value="country">
        Select country
      </option>
      {countries.map(({ id, countryName }) => (
        <option key={id} value={id}>
          {countryName}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
```

it works perfectly. But when I try to pass attributes through props like this:

```
<Select 
          name="country"
          defaultValue="country"
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
          defaultOption="Select Country"
          apiResult={countries}
          dataId={countries.id}
          dataName={countries.countryName}
          disabled="disabled"
        />
```

it fails. Parent component looks like this:

```
const { name, label, onChange, defaultValues, apiResult, defaultOption, dataId, dataName, disabled } = props;
<select name={name} value={defaultValues} onChange={onChange} id="">
    <option disabled={disabled} value={defaultOption}>{defaultOption}</option>
    {apiResult.map(() => (
      <option key={dataId} value={dataId}>
        {dataName}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update parent's state in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537229/how-to-update-parents-state-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

`.map` method must be used in a different way. As first argument you get the current item on the sequence. So:

```js
<select name={name} value={defaultValues} onChange={onChange} id="">
    <option disabled={disabled} value={defaultOption}>{defaultOption}</option>
   {apiResult.map((apiItem) => (
     <option key={apiItem.key} value={apiItem.id}>
       {dataName}
     </option>
   ))}
  </select>
```

So you can call the component like:

```js
<Select 
      name="country"
      defaultValue="country"
      onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
      defaultOption="Select Country"
      apiResult={countries}
      disabled="disabled"
    />
```

`dataId={countries.id}` and `dataName={countries.countryName}` make no sense if `countries` is an array.