# React Pass value from one component to other

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called Auto Complete , where I'm selecting the multiple states using material-ui DownShift. And calling this component in my Registration form component, But How can I get the selected state details in registration component.

Any help appreciated.

Registration form Component

```
import AutoComplete from './autocomplete.js'
.....
 <GridContainer>
                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>

                    <AutoComplete/>
                    </GridItem>
                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                            <CustomInput
                                labelText="Districts Covered"
                                id="usr_org_DistConvered"
                                formControlProps={{
                                    fullWidth: true
                                }}
                                inputProps={{
                                    type: "text",
                                    onChange: (event) => this.handleChange(event),
                                    error: (!!this.state.usr_org_DistConveredError),
                                    helperText: (this.state.usr_org_DistConveredError),
                                }}
                            />

                    </GridItem>
                </GridContainer>
```

autoComplete.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import deburr from "lodash/deburr";
const suggestions = statedist.states;

function renderInput(inputProps) {
  const { InputProps, classes, ref,InputLabelProps, ...other } = inputProps;
console.log(inputProps)
  return (
       <TextField
      InputProps={{
        inputRef: ref,
        classes: {
          root: classes.inputRoot,
          input: classes.inputInput
        },
        ...InputProps
      }}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}

function renderSuggestion(suggestionProps) {
  const {
    suggestion,
    index,
    itemProps,
    highlightedIndex,
    selectedItem
  } = suggestionProps;
  const isHighlighted = highlightedIndex === index;
  const isSelected = (selectedItem || "").indexOf(suggestion.state) > -1;

  return (
    <MenuItem
      {...itemProps}
      key={suggestion.state}
      selected={isHighlighted}
      component="div"
      style={{
        fontWeight: isSelected ? 500 : 400
      }}
    >
      {suggestion.state}
    </MenuItem>
  );
}
renderSuggestion.propTypes = {
  highlightedIndex: PropTypes.number,
  index: PropTypes.number,
  itemProps: PropTypes.object,
  selectedItem: PropTypes.string,
  suggestion: PropTypes.shape({ label: PropTypes.string }).isRequired
};

function getSuggestions(value, { showEmpty = false } = {}) {
  console.log("click");
  const inputValue = deburr(value.trim()).toLowerCase();
  const inputLength = inputValue.length;
  let count = 0;

  return inputLength === 0 && !showEmpty
    ? []
    : suggestions.filter(suggestion => {
        const keep =
          count < 5 &&
          suggestion.state.slice(0, inputLength).toLowerCase() === inputValue;

        if (keep) {
          count += 1;
        }

        return keep;
      });
}

function DownshiftMultiple(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState([]);

  function handleKeyDown(event) {
    if (
      selectedItem.length &&
      !inputValue.length &&
      event.key === "Backspace"
    ) {
      setSelectedItem(selectedItem.slice(0, selectedItem.length - 1));
    }
  }

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleChange(item) {
    let newSelectedItem = [...selectedItem];
    if (newSelectedItem.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      newSelectedItem = [...newSelectedItem, item];
    }
    setInputValue("");
    setSelectedItem(newSelectedItem);
  }

  const handleDelete = item => () => {
    const newSelectedItem = [...selectedItem];
    newSelectedItem.splice(newSelectedItem.indexOf(item), 1);
    setSelectedItem(newSelectedItem);
  };

  return (
    <Downshift
      id="downshift-multiple"
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
      selectedItem={selectedItem}
    >
      {({
        getInputProps,
        getItemProps,
        getLabelProps,
        isOpen,
        inputValue: inputValue2,
        selectedItem: selectedItem2,
        highlightedIndex
      }) => {
        const { onBlur, onChange, onFocus, ...inputProps } = getInputProps({
          onKeyDown: handleKeyDown,
          // placeholder: "Select multiple State"
        });

        return (
          <div className={classes.container}>
            {renderInput({
              fullWidth: true,
              classes,
              // label: "States",
              InputLabelProps: getLabelProps(),
              InputProps: {
                startAdornment: selectedItem.map(item => (
                  <Chip
                    key={item}
                    tabIndex={-1}
                    label={item}
                    className={classes.chip}
                    onDelete={handleDelete(item)}
                  />
                )),
                onBlur,
                onChange: event => {
                  handleInputChange(event);
                  onChange(event);
                },
                onFocus
              },
              inputProps
            })}

            {isOpen ? (
              <Paper className={classes.paper} square>
                {getSuggestions(inputValue2).map((suggestion, index) =>
                  renderSuggestion({
                    suggestion,
                    index,
                    itemProps: getItemProps({ item: suggestion.state }),
                    highlightedIndex,
                    selectedItem: selectedItem2
                  })
                )}
              </Paper>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Downshift>
  );
}

DownshiftMultiple.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};



 function IntegrationDownshift({ ...props }) {
  const classes = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <DownshiftMultiple classes={classes} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default withStyles(customInputStyle)(IntegrationDownshift)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update parent's state in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537229/how-to-update-parents-state-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to share state in React: Context Api, 3rd party state manager(Redux, Flux, MobX), and prop drilling. You might want to look into using the Context Api, as it is probably the easiest and fasted solution that will solve your problem.