# How can I access a state value done in react hooks in another js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a search bar in react which in another file will make a call to the unsplash-api,
I have a search bar component and I am thinking of doing the api call in the main file or if other wise advised in another file in the src folder

So far I have setup a component and setup the initial hook but I dont know how to go forward

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';

const SearchBar = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  return (
    <form>
      <input className="Search" placeholder="Search Images" />
      <button type="submit" id="submit" className="search-button">
        <i className="icon">search</i>
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: [How to update parent's state in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35537229/1218980)

Comment: You should move the state up high enough so that any component that needs it can access it. Context API can be beneficial here.

Comment: That isn't really what `useState` is for: it's a replacement for `this.state` from a class-based component. In the same way you can't access a component's state from the outside, you can't get at the hook. Move it up the chain and pass through props or context. Or use a separate data store.

Comment: In my opinion Using the react `context API` works flawlessly so here is an implementaion using context API. using `useState` will still lead to prop drilling. You can check the answer to a simlar question here [Similar question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870459/how-manage-global-state-using-context-api-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

See if that's what you're looking for. I replaced the `form` for a `div` to avoid submit behavior in the snippet. But the logic is the same. You'll need to do `event.preventDefault` on the submission event.

```js
function mockSearchAPI(searchValue) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Search results for: ' + searchValue), 2000);
  });
}

function App() {

  const [searchResults,setSearchResults] = React.useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

  function doSearch(searchValue) {
    setLoading(true);
    mockSearchAPI(searchValue)
    .then((results) => {
      setSearchResults(results);
      setLoading(false);
     });
  }


  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <SearchBar
        doSearch={doSearch}
      />
      {loading &&
        <div>Loading...</div>
      }
      {searchResults && 
        <div>{searchResults}</div>
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const SearchBar = (props) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState('');
  
  function onClick() {
    console.log(search);
    props.doSearch(search);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        //className="Search" 
        placeholder="Search Images" 
        onChange={(event)=>setSearch(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button 
        //type="submit"
        //id="submit"
        //className="search-button"
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        <i className="icon">search</i>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you should be able to pass the state in Hooks (from the search bar) to the parent component in these methods.

1. Use Redux and create a global store with the required state
   variable. Then from the search component you will need to update the
   state variable in the Redux store, then load this state variable in
   the parent component.
2. Create a state variable from the parent component and have it
   passed to the search component as a prop. Then from the search
   component, you will update this prop.

I am not not 100% sure if method 2 will work as expected but I am pretty sure method 1 will work.