# How can I pass a child component's state up to the parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS. Please forgive me if it is so simple.

I am trying to inject the radio button component (RadioButton.js) into home page. So that the radio button appear on home page. It like a child. As you can see from `RadioButton.js`, I have two radio buttons. Their values are `buttonOne` and `buttonTwo`.

What I am trying to achieve is that when `buttonOne` is selected, I would like to show `<TablePage/>` components. otherwise, `<StickyHeadTable />`

**RadioButton.js**

```
export default function FormControlLabelPosition() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("female");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label="position"
        name="position"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        row
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          value="buttonOne"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="F1"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="buttonTwo"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="F2"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

`RadioButton` is injected in homepage. How can i get the values from `RadioButton.js`. So that I can use the condition.

**HomePage.js**

```
  return (
    <div className="home-page">
      <RadioButton values={values} handleChange={handleChange}></RadioButton>
      {values.flight === "buttonOne" ? <TablePage /> : <StickyHeadTable />}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: 1. add a function to `HomePage.js` that changes the page 2. pass it as prop to `<RadioButton>` 3. call it from inside the child's `handleChange`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update parent's state in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537229/how-to-update-parents-state-in-react)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `value` from the `RadioButton` component, you should create it as an uncontrolled form component meaning that its `value` would come from it's parent, in this case the `HomePage` component.

So the **RadioButton.js** would be:

```
export default function RadioButton({ value, onChange }) {
  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label="position"
        name="position"
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        row
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          value="buttonOne"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="F1"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="buttonTwo"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="F2"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

RadioButton.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

And the **HomePage.js**

```
    export default function HomePage() {
      const [value, setValue] = React.useState("buttonOne");

      const handleChange = event => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
      };

      return (
        <div className="home-page">
          <RadioButton value={value} onChange={handleChange}></RadioButton>
          {value === "buttonOne" ? <TablePage /> : <StickyHeadTable />}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Please check for duplicates before answering; this question is a clear duplicate.

Comment: Please add the following to avoid props validation warning:  `export default function RadioButton({ value, onChange }) { RadioButton.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };` ....} and i will accept your solution

Answer (score 2):

RadioButton.js

```
export default function FormControlLabelPosition(props) {

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label="position"
        name="position"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.handleChange}
        row
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          value="buttonOne"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="F1"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="buttonTwo"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="F2"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

HomePage.js

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("female");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };
 return (
    <div className="home-page">
      <RadioButton values={values} handleChange={handleChange}></RadioButton>
      {values.flight === "buttonOne" ? <TablePage /> : <StickyHeadTable />}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Please check for duplicates before answering; this question is a clear duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

On the HomePage.js you can use state for showing up the **table** conditionally based on radio button value.

I assume **RadioButton.js** component is called in **HomePage.j**s as component.

**RadioButton.js**

```
export default function FormControlLabelPosition(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("female");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);


>  //Send your radio button value to parent component i.e HomePage.js

    props.handleChange(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label="position"
        name="position"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        row
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          value="buttonOne"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="F1"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="buttonTwo"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="F2"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

**HomePage.js**

```
state = {
      radioButtonValue: '';
}

render () {
   return (
        <div className="home-page">
          <RadioButton handleChange={this.handleChange} />
          {this.state.radioButtonValue === "buttonOne" ?
                 <TablePage /> : <StickyHeadTable />}
       </div>
  );
}

handleChange = (radioButtonValue) => {
          this.setState({radioButtonValue});
}
```

One the above code, we are sending handleChange as a props and change the state as soon as radio-button is clicked and then rendering the table based on the state.