# Trying to change state in Parent from Child component React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been looking through related posts and tried a few solutions but I wasn't able to adapt any of them to my situation.
I am trying to change the state of `selectedPin` by sending the function and calling it from the child component.

See below my code

Parent component :

```
export default function Pins(data) {
const chargers = data.data;
const [selectedPin, setSelectedPin] = useState(null);

const handleClose = () => {
setSelectedPin(null);
};

return (
<>
  {chargers.map((charger, index) => (
    <Marker
      key={index}
      longitude={charger.AddressInfo.Longitude}
      latitude={charger.AddressInfo.Latitude}
    >
      <Button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setSelectedPin(charger);
        }}
      >
        <img src="./assets/pin.svg" alt="marker pin" />
      </Button>
    </Marker>
  ))}
  {selectedPin ? (
    <PopupInfo selectedPin={selectedPin} handleClose={handleClose} />
  ) : null}
 </>
 );
}
```

Child component :

```
export default function PopupInfo(selectedPin, { handleClose }) {
const pin = selectedPin.selectedPin;
console.log(pin);
console.log(handleClose);

return (
<Popup
  latitude={pin.AddressInfo.Latitude}
  longitude={pin.AddressInfo.Longitude}
  onClose={handleClose}
  >
    <div>Popup Info</div>
  </Popup>
  );
}
```

When console logging `handleClose` in child component I am getting `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should pass them both down as named props:

`export default function PopupInfo({ selectedPin, handleClose })`

or do this:

`export default function PopupInfo(props)` and then use `props.selectedPin` and `props.handleClose`.

Comment: I think this would solve the problem and when passing the handleClose fn to the child component make sure wrap it in useCallback hook

Comment: Your second option worked. Thank you! I would also give you an upvote but my rep is to low...

Comment: This work's but not the right approach. @mcAdam, Kindly refer the documentations and advantages of Uni-directional data flow.

Comment: @NandhaFrost I think you are getting confused. this isn't breaking the laws of uni-directional flow. it's well documented you can pass props down to child components to update parent state

Answer (score 0):

*It won't work as React is **Uni-directional** data flow model* - it'a core feature of React.

State of Parent can't be modified by Child. You have to come-up with an idea to handle the data in Parent itself or pass that as prop to bypass(not recommended)

If you are interested to know more : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hO8u07-WTOk

Comment: this isn't true. you can modify state of parent from child if you pass down the props from parent to child and set it that way.

Comment: No I can't be wrong. That's the major reason for having Unidirectional data flow model

Comment: please, it isn't breaking uni directional flow. it's perfectly okay to pass props down to update parent state

Comment: Thanks for the video. This does sound interesting and quite different to how Treehouse and Udacity teach Parent & Child Components relations

Comment: @mcAdam please see this question and accepted answer for a better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537229/how-to-update-parents-state-in-react

Comment: Thank you @RedBaron. I ended up using your method multiple times throughout my project to pass props through components. In the future I will try to implement a global state using a context hook. Thank you for the link I will have a look