# How can I pass a prop from child to parent component

Tags: reactjs

How can I pass a prop (when modified) from Child Component to a Parent Component.

Some Details :
I am working on an existing codebase where I have Parent Component embedded in
'unstated.Container' and a separate Child Component , where I am trying to add a button. When
a user clicks this button some value gets updated , which needs to be passed to the Parent
component .

Thank you.

```
 import {Container} from 'unstated';

   class DelContainer extends Container{

     state = { sortAsc : true, notified : null}

    setVal = async (Id, value)  => { console.log (`Id : ${Id});  console.log('value: ${value}); }

}

//Child Component (Separate file)
const ChildItems = (props) => {
  const [some_value ] = props;
  const [some_color, setColor] = useState(" ");

 const MarkIt = ({some_value})
 {
   some_value = this.props.some_value;  //ISSUE HERE
 }

 return (
   <IconButton >
      <StarOutlinedIcon onClick = {MarkIt} style={{color: `${some_color}`}}/>
   </IconButton>
 );
}

//Parent Component (Separate file)
import {Subscribe} from 'unstated';
const DelList = (props) => {

    return(

        <Subscribe to ={[DelContainer]}>
        {
           (delStore) => {
                   const[person, isLoading] = delStore.state;
             return(
                     <div>
                        <List className = {props.className} isLoading = {Loading}>
                        {
                             isLoading && person
                               .map((person, index)=>{
                                 return <ChildItem key={index}
                                           person = {person}
                                           some_value = {delStore.MarkIt(some_value)}; 
                                           
                               }
                        }
                       </List<
                     </div>
                   )
          }
        }
      );
 }
```

Comment: It's done via callbacks https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/easy-tutorial-on-react-callbacks-fad6a51cc8f1

Comment: please take a look at the react documentation here - https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Read this :
[How to update parent's state in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537229/how-to-update-parents-state-in-react)

### Reactjs DOCS:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  liftStateHander=()=> {
    this.setState({
       name:"John"
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <Child handler={this.liftStateHander} />
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <button onClick={this.props.handler}>
          Click For Change State Parent 
       </button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27890565)

Comment: Okay. you Give me a Score

Comment: Editing your answer is a good first step, as your original answer—which relied primarily on a link—would have been deleted. Now, people will have the opportunity to upvote your answer if and when they find your answer useful. Please don’t demand upvotes; that’s up to each member of the community to decide based on whether your answer was useful to them.

Comment: OK. I did not know that ‍♂️‍♂️. Thank you for saying that. 

Comment: Well, all of this is explained in [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ;-).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the the documentation

Comment: can you pass data from child js to parent tsx component?