# Update parent component state with a function whose arguments rely on child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know it **seems** like a duplicate from [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537229/how-to-update-parents-state-in-react) but it's not, I need to do something slightly different that's not working.

I'm implementing:

- a componente `<Page/>` which has two child components:

  - a `<Greetings/>` message.
  - a `<LoginButton/>` button.

`<Page/>` has a `{isLogged: false}` state. `<Greetings/>` should display different messages when `isLogged` is true/false.

`<LoginButton/>` should have a `login` text when `isLogged`'s false, `logout` otherwise, and implement a function that updates `isLogged` state from its parent component, `<Page/>`.

With this implementation, I'm willing to learn:

- `<Greetings/>`: How to implement a child component whose props are binded to the parents component state (works)
- `<LoginButton/>`: How to update parent's state from a child component, passing parent's `setState` for the child through its props (**is not working**).

Here's my source code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class Greetings extends React.Component{
  render(){
    if(this.props.isLogged){
      return <p>You're logged. Welcome Back!</p>
    }
    return <p>You're not logged. Please Login</p>
  }
}

class LoginButton extends React.Component{
  login(){
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.handler({isLogged: true})
  }

  logout(){
    this.props.handler({isLogged: false})
  }
  
  render(){
    if(this.props.isLogged){
      return <button onClick = {()=>{this.logout()}}>logout</button> 
    }
    return <button onClick = {()=>{this.login()}}>login</button>
  }
}

class Page extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {isLogged: false}
  }

  handler(newState){
    this.setState(newState)
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <>
      <Greetings isLogged={this.state.isLogged}/>
      <LoginButton isLogged={this.state.isLogged} handler = {()=>this.handler}/>
      </>
    )
  }
}

const element = <Page/>
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The main difference between my code and most of examples from the other StackOverflow question is that it's up to the child component, `<LoginButton/>`, to decide the arguments for calling `this.render`, which's causing me problems.

I believe there's something wrong on `login()` and `logout()` functions, but i'm not managing to discover what.

[image]

The page renders, but the button's not working. Please helpe me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are expecting and argument in your this.handle but not passing the value from the props. this should fix your problem.

```
class Page extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {isLogged: false}
  }

  handler(newState){
    console.log(newState)
    this.setState(newState)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <>
      <Greetings isLogged={this.state.isLogged}/>
      <LoginButton handler = {(newState) => this.handler(newState)}/>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Or you can aslo do it by binding your handler function and simply passing it to the child component as prop, rather than calling it.

```
class Pageextends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {isLogged: false}
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
  }

  handler(newState){
    console.log(newState)
    this.setState(newState)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <>
      <Greetings isLogged={this.state.isLogged}/>
      <LoginButton handler = {this.handler}/>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that too! I prefer arrow functions over bindings but I see why some may prefer the other way

Comment: Yeah I also prefer arrow functions

Answer (score 1):

You are providing arguments in this line

```
 this.props.handler({isLogged: true})
```

but not receiving in the handler prop passed to the LoginButton component
The render method of Page component should be like:

```
 render(){
    return(
      <>
      <Greetings isLogged={this.state.isLogged}/>
      <LoginButton isLogged={this.state.isLogged} handler = {(newState)=>this.handler(newState)}/>
      </>
    )
  }
```