# How to access to change te State of a component from an other

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

Any body knows how can I change the true value of SetIsOpen from my component BottomSheetBtn? I think I tryed every thing I know but it results me impossible

````
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet, {BottomSheetView} from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import BottomSheetBtn from './BottomSheetBtn';


export default function UserInksBottomSheet(){
   
   const sheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);
   const [isOpen, SetIsOpen] = useState(true);
   
   const snapPoints = ['60%','90%']

   return(
      <BottomSheet
         ref={sheetRef}
         snapPoints={snapPoints}
      >
         <BottomSheetView style={styles.container}>
            BOTTOMSHEET CONTENT
            <BottomSheetBtn/> <--- This button is which needs to change the state
         </BottomSheetView>
      </BottomSheet>

   );
}```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update parent state based on props and onClick from child in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643206/update-parent-state-based-on-props-and-onclick-from-child-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it as props in the main component:

```
<BottomSheetBtn isOpen={isOpen} SetIsOpen={SetIsOpen}/>
```

Change the value in the BottomSheet Component as if it's a regular function:

```
const changeValue = () => props.SetIsOpen(!props.isOpen)
```

Comment: Hey, I just tried at this moment, and it still doesn't work, I don't know why. It doesn't throw any err, it just keeps like nothing happened

Comment: Please show your code BottomSheetBtn Component code

Comment: sorry was my bad, jajaj. Now it is working. btw, do you know how to do the same thing but passing it to an other component

Answer (score 0):

Pass the setIsOpen function to the onPress Functionality of the BottomSheetBtn Component.

```
<BottomSheetBtn onPress={() => SetIsOpen(!isOpen)}/> // this will provide the toggle functionality.
```

and then pass the onPress props to the TouchableOpacity or the Button component in the body of BottomSheetBtn

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} >
{...}
</TouchableOpacity>
```