# Can I setState in Parent from Child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I would like to clean my code a bit so instead of having one long component I would like to create child component.

In my `Parent` I have some states I would like to update `onClick` in `Child`.

**Parent:**

```
const [plan, setPlan] = useState('myPlan');
const [months, setMonths] = useState('2');
const [price, setPrice] = useState(200);

<PlanSelection props={props}
               item={selectedData}
               itemPlan={plan}
 />
```

**Child**

```
const PlanSelection = ({ props, item, itemPlan }) => {

    function handleSubsribe() {
        props.setPlan('Subsribe Only');
        props.setPrice(item.price);
        props.setMonths('24+');
    }

    function handlePay() {
        props.setPlan('Pay to Own');
        props.setPrice(item.pay);
        props.setMonths('12-24');
    }
```

And just trying to call the functions (in Child component)

```
<button onClick={handleSubscribe} />
<button onClick={handlePay} />
```

Using the code above throws error after clicking in one of the buttons:

**TypeError: props.setPlan is not a function**

But if I don't pass props, setPlan, setPrice, .... will be undefined. Is there a way how to handle it ?

Comment: You can, but `handleSubsribe()` and `handlePay()` should be declared in the parent component and passed to the child as props.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update the parent's state in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537229/how-can-i-update-the-parents-state-in-react)

Comment: This is an example of what I meant in my previous comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bcs6ejpk/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

```js
<PlanSelection props={props}
               item={selectedData}
               itemPlan={plan}
 />
```

You did not pass `setPlan` to child, you have only passed `props`, which `props` has nothing to do with `state`, `selectedData` which I'm not sure what's that, and `plan`, which is the `state`. In summary you did not pass anything about `setState` to child component

---

### Solution

**Parent**

```js
const [plan, setPlan] = useState('myPlan');

<PlanSelection 
  setPlan={setPlan}
 />
```

**Child**

```js
const PlanSelection = ({ setPlan }) => {

    function handleSubsribe() {
        setPlan('Subsribe Only');
    }

    function handlePay() {
        setPlan('Pay to Own');
    }
```

In the code above I've only used `setPlan` as an example to show you how to `setState` from child component, you can apply same logic to the rest.

**UPDATES**
Just realized I've made a mistake which you should be worth noting. In your child component you have `({ setPlan })`, this is known as destructuring, which is you are extracting `setPlan` out of `props`, hence in your child component, you should not be accessing `props.setPlan` but `setPlan` instead. Do take a look at the answer above again

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass your setState functions as props to your child component. One simple way to do that is:

```
const [plan, setPlan] = useState('myPlan');
const [months, setMonths] = useState('2');
const [price, setPrice] = useState(200);

<PlanSelection setPlan={setPlan}
               item={selectedData}
               itemPlan={plan}
 />
```

Here you will be able to update plan state from the child component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass all your setStates to the child, try this.

```
const handlers = {setPlan, setMonths, setPrice}
    <PlanSelection handlers={handlers}
                   item={selectedData}
                   itemPlan={plan}
     />

const PlanSelection = ({ handlers, item, itemPlan }) => {
```

You can use `setPlan` as `handlers.setPlan` instead of `props.setPlan`.

Comment: I dont think `props={...props}` is a good idea, first of all, we should never name `props`, `props`. Second, kinda personal preference, i dont really wanna pass all parent's `props` over to child, after all we human never inherit all the traits from our parent, do we :p

Comment: Agreed. Passing `props` directly to the child is not my favorite too.