# Next js send form data to parent page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I create a simple page called lucky number

`pages/lucky.js`

```js
import finder from '../../hooks/use-finder'
import NumberForm from '../components/number-form'
export default function LuckyNumber() {
  const { data } = finder(number)
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Lucky Number</h1>
      <NumberForm />
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
export default function NumberForm() {
  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <label>
          Number:
          <input type="text" name="number" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

where `NumberForm` is a form where user can just input a number `ex: 12345`. Once use submits the form, I want to pass that number to my hook in the page `finder(number)` so I can check to see if that number is in my lucky list of numbers.

How can I pass the number that user submits to the page?

Comment: pass a submit handler to `NumberForm` that sets an state in the parent component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update the parent's state in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66186184/11613622)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use parent `state` and send the `setState` to the child to update it i.e.

`pages/lucky.js`

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import finder from '../../hooks/use-finder'
import NumberForm from '../components/number-form'
export default function LuckyNumber() {
  const [number, setnumber] = useState(0);
  const { data } = finder(number)
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Lucky Number</h1>
      <NumberForm onChange={setnumber} />
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
export default function NumberForm({ onChange }) {
  const [number, setnumber] = useState(0);
  const handleChange = (event)=>{
    setNumber(event?.target?.value)
  }
  const handleSubmit = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    onChange(number)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <label>
          Number:
          <input type="text" name="number" value={number} onChange={ handleChange } />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={ handleSubmit } />
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```