# Update the state in parent with onclick in CHild in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a state in parent component which i want to update it from `onClick` in the child component, but it is not updating what is wrong here?

**Another Problem**
I want to show a popup when the user click in one of the radio button. And i have different popup messages for each radio button. I am using the index to show this popup. But how can i tell the child component to show this clicked popup?

**Parent**

```
 const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(-1);

 return (
    <div>
      {options?.map((option,index) => (
        <RadioBtn
          key={index}
          onChange={radioButtonChangeHandler}
          label={option.label}
          value={option.value}
          showPopup={showPopup}
         activeIndex={activeIndex}
          onClick={() => {
            setShowPopup(curr => !curr);
            setActiveIndex(index);
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

**Child**

```
const popupMessage = (<div>{infoContent</div>);
 
return (
    <div className={clsx("radio-button", infoContent && "has-info")}>
      <Popup open={showPopup}>
        <PopupPositionReference>
          <div className="radio-button-popup-icon onClick={props.onClick}>
            <input
              ref={iRef => {
                ref(iRef);
                inputRef.current = iRef;
              }}
              type="radio"
              checked={isChecked}
              {...props}
              {...rest}
            />
            <label htmlFor={id}>
              {label}
            </label>
          </div>
        </PopupPositionReference>
        {popupMessage && <PopupContent>{popupMessage}</PopupContent>}
      </Popup>
    </div>
  );
```

CSS

```
.radio-button {
  &.has-info {
    .radio-button-popup-icon {
      position: relative;

      &::after {
        content: " ";
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        background-image: url(...);
        background-position: right;
        background-size: contain;
      }
    }
}
``
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update the parent's state in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537229/how-can-i-update-the-parents-state-in-react)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the setShowPopup properly.

If you want to toggle the state

```
onClick={() => setShowPopup((curr)=> !curr)}
```

If you just want to set it to true

```
onClick={() => setShowPopup(true)}
```

##### Second issue

You can use the index in the showPopup prop

```
showPopup={showPopup && index === activeIndex}
```

You could probably even get rid of the showPopup state, depending on how the popup works

```
showPopup={index === activeIndex}
```

If you always want to show the popup of the checked radio you could even get rid of the activeIndex state and the `showPopup` prop in the child component and just use isChecked

```
<Popup open={isChecked}>
```

##### Final solution

Keep it simple, since we no only want to show the popup on a click on a icon. We can remove all states and just add the popup and icon next to the radio button. Based on what package you use for the `popup`it should be able to open and close the popup on click on the icon without a external state needed.

```js
<input
 type="radio"
checked={isChecked}
/>
{popupMessage && <Popup>
  <PopupPositionReference>
    <YourIconHere />
  </PopupPositionReference>
   <PopupContent>{popupMessage}</PopupContent>
</Popup>}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :). I updated the question with another problem can you help me in that?

Comment: I think that you have to update the question again, the `Child` code seems to be broken. Could you elaborate a bit mor about what the second issue really are?

Comment: i updated the child component, the problem is that i want to click on the radio button to show its corresponding popup message. I used the index state but i don't know how to check this index to show the required popup message.

Comment: See updated answer, its always recommended to try to use as few states as possible and keep the states as close to where they are used.

Comment: Thanks again :) I have one more question, if i have an icon after this radio button and i want the popup to be shown only `onClick` of this icon not in the radio button itself, what i have to change in the code now?. I added the icon as a css `::after`

Comment: In that case just add the icon and popup separately from the input no need to do it the hard way by altering css.